# Using "Stratiplot" with data from Neotoma

Tags: r

:) Hey there!

1.) I am unfortunately a little bit  unexperienced in R. Yet at least I have found a possible possibility to plot a pollen diagram with the help of R.

There are actually a bunch of packages to do this... whatever. For instance, there is the `Stratiplot()` from a package called `analogue`.

The author made an example for a certain dataset that I don't have:

```
require(analogue)
data(abernethy)
Stratiplot(Age ~ . - Depth, data = chooseTaxa(abernethy, n.occ = 5, max.abun = 10),
           type = c("h","l","g"))
```

So far, so good.

2.) Now there is the package "neotoma" which is, I guess, created for the handling of data from the neotoma explorer, in which worldwide pollen data can be found. For instance there is the code `get_dataset()`in which you can put an ID sepcific to the site where the pollen was sampled.

like so: `pollen_data <-get_dataset(2508)`

There is another way to get the data: To download it from the neotoma explorer, as a .csv file. --> [Neotoma-Explorer](http://apps.neotomadb.org/explorer/)

3) So my question is, how can I actually link the dataset(2508) with the `Stratiplot()` so I can get a (very basic) diagram?

I know this is a big thing yet maybe can give me a hint, e.g. on where to start?! Thanks a lot!

Many regards! Vera

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this time it worked:

```
pollyanna<-get_download(309)
Stratiplot(pollyanna)
```

neotoma does everything... :)